# What's the google cloud configuration I need for hosting wordpress site having 20,000 visits daily

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have a wordpress site hosted on dedicated server having below configuration.

- **CPU (8 cores)**: Intel Xeon CPU E3-1265L v3 @ 2.50GHz,
- **Memory**: 24GB,
- **Currently Used Storage**: 350GB,
- **MySQL size**: 3GB,

I have maximum daily visitors of 20,000 and maximum concurrent users at any point would be 400.

I would like to know which Google Cloud "**Compute Engine**" I should choose to cater these many requests without compromising the performance. Also, what are the other required resource I need to buy?
Is **AWS** better for this than **GCP** in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nobody can give you an answer to this type of question. It totally depends upon the application setup and the pattern of usage. The best way to determine this would be to create an **automated test system** that simulates usage in a pattern similar to how your website will be used, then to monitor the system (CPU, RAM usage, etc) and determine performance.

Alternatively, you can choose to **oversize** the system and monitor real-life metrics. Then, scale-down the system such that the metrics stay within acceptable ranges. It is relatively cheap to over-size systems in the cloud given that it might only be for a week.